# Is the asynchronous part of Apple's new verification controller necessary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I was looking through Apple's Verification Controller patch for In App Purchases here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html

I was planning on implementing server validation, but to not necessitate a response immediately.

Is the asynchronous part of their new code absolutely necessary. Does it offer any advantage over a naive server side validation?

If I could just use the immediate parsing and checking and gain a benefit, that would be great.

Thanks!

EDIT: This question feels a little empty without some code:

I'm talking specifically about changing the main verifyPurchase function to contain only:

```
- (BOOL)verifyPurchase:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
{
    return [self isTransactionAndItsReceiptValid:transaction];
}
```

...and get rid of the client -> server post. Will I still be vulnerable to the recent hacks?

Comment: If you don't mind blocking the main thread, sure. This tends to be a big no-no, especially in areas with poor network coverage (the connection might take a long time before it times out).

Comment: This is exactly the code as it is at the moment. All I've done is remove the networking part. As far as I can tell, there will be no network access from this chunk of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question makes much more sense after looking at the code.

The attack in question is that someone presents *someone else's* otherwise-valid receipt. There does not appear to be anything in the receipt data that ties it to the device/purchaser. You can mitigate this to some extent by checking the purchase dates (but *only* if the device has accurate time, which is under the user's control).

(This attack would not work if the *client* generated a 256-bit random nonce which had to match the receipt. An attacker can obviously hack the binary/PRNG, but in either case you've already lost.)

Incidentally, the code has a bunch of problems:

- The only check of the server cert is that it's an EV cert. This should be easy to forge, since the attacker has complete control of the CA.
- A transaction ID is permanently added to the list of "already seen" transactions in `-isTransactionAndItsReceiptValid:` before the network check finishes, but the content is only unlocked after the network returns. The receipt can never be re-verified if the connection fails, so the user's money will have effectively gone into a black hole.
- It expects the transaction to have occurred on the same device that is verifying it.
- It expects ITC_CONTENT_PROVIDER_SHARED_SECRET to be embedded in the executable (trivial to decrypt with a jailbroken device).
- It assumes that `-connection:didReceiveData:` returns the complete receipt data (this might not be the case due to fragmentation, but it can probably be guaranteed since Apple controls the server implementation).